# Installing my mysql adapter properly

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php5, pdo

I am running on ubuntu 10.04. Can someone tell me how to isntall:

- PHP5
- MySQL with support for PDO

All tutorials I've found are a bit old.

Comment: Have you actually tried some of those tutorials, or are you simply ignoring them because you feel they're "a bit old"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-mysql php-db mysql-server mysql-client
```

That should get you going. Possibly replace *apache2* with the webserver software of your choice.